# Maintaining a Dev Version of a Web App

Tags: git, web-applications

I am working on a webapp, and I'd like to setup a separate dev version so that I may test the app before I deploy it to live.

The tools I am currently using are: apache, git, python, mysql.

What would be some good practices to setting this up? I think I would like to have `http://dev.website.com` display the dev version.

Also, once I am satisfied, what would be a good way to push the dev version to prod?

Answer (score 0):

Using git you can maintain a development branch of your app, and when feeling confident about your work you can merge it with the master branch of the app.

Additionally its important to have your deployment strategy and systems in place at the beginning of your project so you can deploy at any time, I recommend that you have a development server which you deploy your development branch to (the server should be identical to the production server). A popular deployment system with Ruby is `Capistrano` I'm sure there is something similar for python too!